# Strange JSON output with Phil Sturgeon's REST Server, PHP, Codeigniter

Tags: php, rest, api, codeigniter-3

I am working with [Phil Sturgeon's REST server](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver).  I get the following output from a GET request for a simple blog table I have (just test data):

```
{
"user_id": "1",
"entryid": "1",
"entry_name": "twkla nnn xxx",
"entry_body": "this is just UPDATED",
"status": "active",
"created_timestamp": "2016-05-01 21:25:51",
"updated_timestamp": "2016-11-12 17:29:38"
}
```

The url is like this:

```
https://www.example.com/v1/Blog/blog/id/1
```

However, when I make a get request for a id that doesn't exist, I get the following:

```
No webpage was found for the web address: 
https://www.example.com/v1/Blog/blog/id/233
HTTP ERROR 404
```

I was hoping it would say no data found.  How is that implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, lots of ways to reply to a resource request.  Here is the reply for no such blog found;

```
// Set the response and exit
   $this->response([
       'status' => FALSE,
       'message' => 'No such blog was found'
   ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND); // NOT_FOUND (404) being the HTTP response code
```